# SendGrid Contacts API

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm trying to add a recipient into my contacts list. Here's the code:

````
this._client = new SendGridClient(this._options.Value.SendGridKey);

var recipientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var uri = new Uri($"{BASE_URL}/contactdb/recipients");
            var httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            var emailModel = new EmailModel()
            {
                email = email,
                name = "Anna",
                age = 26.ToString(),
                pet = "caaaaat"
            };
            var emailJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailModel); 
            httpMessage.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(EmailModel), emailModel, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            var response = await this._client.MakeRequest(httpMessage);```

The code returns bad request, and I just don't know why. Anyone else had this problem?
````

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST

Comment: The API expects the payload to be passed as collection of contacts while you are passing a single object to the API. You need to create a list of EmailModel, add a new object to it and JSON serialize the list and then pass it to the API.